# Outlook 2016 presenting "Something went wrong and you search couldn't be completed," but the search is actually completing fine

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2016

This problem has been presenting for months, and as far as I can tell is a graphical issue, it's just reporting an error that isn't actually happening.

This is happening when the user is doing a contact search, all of the contacts he's looking for show up. But, the error is still present at the top of the results page.

Things I have tried:

- Creating a new profile
- Repairing the .ost
- Checked for third-party add-ins, none found.
- Deleted PreventIndexingOutlook Key
- Enabled Search Indexing: This actually made it so that searching didn't work at all.
- Reset Outlook indexing.

Anyone else ever encountered this issue?

Comment: if none of those help, you may upgrade office to test the results

Answer (score 0):

If you've already tried rebuilding the index (`Control Panel -> Indexing Options -> Microsoft Outlook -> ADVANCED button -> REBUILD button`) with no luck, try repairing Microsoft Office.
There was a bad update a while back that broke searching until Office was repaired.  You'll find the repair option for the regular Office (not 365) in `Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Microsoft Office [Professional] 2016 -> right-click and choose repair`.